# how to use phone as screen for xbox 360

Tags: xbox-360, android

How do I use an Android phone as an Xbox 360 monitor? My TV stopped working and I'm looking into it. Is it possible to use my Android phone for the Xbox 360 Slim so I can play my games that are on the Xbox?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This isn't possible without an extra device.
An android phone usually doesn't have a HDMI-Input and the OTG-Adapter usually can only be used as an HDMI-Output.

There is a way described online which uses a USB-Capture-Card and a OTG-Adapter to feed the Signal as a USB-Webcam into your smartphone, which can be used by Apps.
https://www.diyphotography.net/convert-any-android-phone-into-an-hdmi-monitor/

(Haven't used it myself, so no guarantee that it works)

Comment: I did order the video capture and I will try and give my feedback

Comment: It's worked you are genius